# Minimising an expression involving prime numbers.

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, discrete-optimization, coprime, combinatorial-number-theory

I would like to solve the following problem for a general $n$:

> Find disjoint sets $P$ and $Q$ of prime numbers so that
> \begin{align*}
> \pi_P = \prod_{p \in P} p \leq n \textrm{ and } \pi_Q = \prod_{q \in Q} q \leq n
> \end{align*}
> and the expression
> \begin{align*}
> B(P, Q) &= \Big(\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{\pi_P} \Big\rfloor + 1\Big)\prod_{p \in P} p - 1
>     + \Big(\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{\pi_Q} \Big\rfloor + 1\Big)\prod_{q \in Q} q - 1 \\ &=
> \Big(\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{\pi_P} \Big\rfloor + 1\Big)\varphi(\pi_P)
>     + \Big(\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{\pi_Q} \Big\rfloor + 1\Big)\varphi(\pi_Q)
> \end{align*}
> is minimised.

I am also interested in any heuristically good solutions where there is no proof of minimality. This problem comes from the bounding the Cheeger constant for the graph with vertex set $[n]$, in which two vertices are adjacent if and only if they are relatively prime.

I should perhaps demonstrate that I have made some attempt on this problem. We can continue bounding above to obtain
\begin{align}
\Big(\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{\pi_P} \Big\rfloor + 1\Big)\varphi(\pi_P)
    + \Big(\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{\pi_Q} \Big\rfloor + 1\Big)\varphi(\pi_Q) \leq
\Big(\frac{n}{\pi_P} + 1\Big)\pi_P
    + \Big(\frac{n}{\pi_Q} + 1\Big)\pi_Q = 2n + \pi_P + \pi_Q
\end{align}
and this suggests that we should take $P = \{2\}$ and $Q = \{3\}$. This gives $B(\{2\}, \{3\}) = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 2\lfloor n/3 \rfloor + 3$, but much information is lost when we bound as we just have and so I do not think that this solution is minimal.